# How can I Show a error 500 page in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Currently, I am working on a project in Laravel 8. for this I want to make some custom error pages specifically a 404 and a 500 page. I want to visit these pages via http://127.0.0.1:8000//404 or http://127.0.0.1:8000//500 so I can showcase them. Now I am able to get the 404 page to show with http://127.0.0.1:8000/404 but not the 500 page. And I am unable to find sources on the internet that go into this regarding Larvel 8.
Is there anyone here that knows how I will be able to manage this? It would be a great help!

Comment: create a route for the `/500` page and simply call `abort(500)` in the controller action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a route for it and return the status code.

```
Route::get('/500', fn() => abort(500));
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding custom pages for errors will not simply override the existing error templates. First, you need to publish Laravel's default error page templates using the `vendor:publish` Artisan command. Once the templates have been published, you may customize them to your liking:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-errors
```

You can add temporary routes as @Daan said to view the error pages.